# iterating over const matrix and vector

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I have a function with constant matrix and vector as input, and i am trying to iterate over columns as follows

```
void matx_mut(const int *A, const int **B, unsigned int c, unsigned int a_col_start, unsigned int a_col_end,     unsigned int a_row_start, unsigned int a_row_end)
{
        unsigned int i
        int  *a_ptr, *b_ptr;
        // do initial processing

        for( i = a_col_start; i <= a_col_end; i++)
        {
            // some code 

            a_ptr = &A[a_col_start];
            b_ptr = &B[i][a_row_start];

            // more code 

        }
}
```

However, I am getting the following warning "warning C4090: '=' : different 'const' qualifiers" . I can't change a_ptr and b_ptr to const because I am changing their value on every iteration, right?

is there a nice way to resolve this warning?, beside declaring both pointers inside the 2nd for loop.

I tried using initial pointers A and B, but this made it not easy to read :(

Comment: did (not) you miss a `;`?

Comment: and something like `a_row_start` definition?

Comment: If you modify `a_ptr[0]`, you are actually modifying `A[a_col_start]`, which is exactly what `const int *A` tries to stop you from doing.

Comment: Is there a reason to make them const? If you're changing their values, you shouldn't use const.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, thanks, I forgot to type it. I edited my original post.

Comment: @The PC Luddite : A and B are not changed , they're accessed /read, and their values are used to modify a global variable. Using const makes reading the code much easier for everyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the description of [c4090](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k77bkb8d.aspx) warning,

> A variable used in an operation is defined with a specified modifier that prevents it from being modified without detection by the compiler. The expression is compiled without modification.
>
> This warning can be caused when a pointer to a const or volatile item is assigned to a pointer not declared as pointing to const or volatile.

**Reason:** In your code

```
 a_ptr = &A[a_col_start];
 b_ptr = &B[i][a_row_start];
```

the target pointers are non-`const`, the source pointers are. In this case, if you try to modify the value of (*through*) `a_ptr`, according to the standard, chapter §6.7.3

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.. [...]

You'll face undefined behavior. So, the compiler is warning you about the potential UB you might face later due to modification of values through the non-const pointers.

The point here is, the warning is there for a reason, try to *solve* the possible issue, don't try to *suppress* it.

Also, I think, you're missing the understanding of `const` type qualifier. In case of a definition like

```
 const int * a_ptr;
```

`a_ptr` is not a *constant*, `*a_ptr` is. So, you can make the `a_ptr` and `b_ptr` pointers as `const` and assign them values inside the loop. As per the `const` property, you cannot change the value at the location pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. All of this information was already stated. The OP just really wants to violate the const qualifier instead of making the parameters non-const.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, thanks for the information. Previously, I thought when put const int * a_ptr, I will have the value in *a_ptr and a_ptr as const. However, your explanation cleared this. I changed int *a_ptr to const int * a_ptr, and the warning is gone.